# How to download auto generated file in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am created a basic ocr system. When user uploads a PDF file to system ocr read it and created a xlsm file with the same name. I am using remote control with Azure (Windows). I created a download button. When I click it, downloads the file with same name, so it should work but appears a error.
[image: The Error]

How can I fix this problem?

```
<a href= "{% static path %}" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" download>Download Report File</a>
```

in my views:

```
name = pdf.pdf.name.replace(".xlsm", "").replace(".pdf", "")
path = "C:/user/ocr/" + name + ".xlsm"
```

Note: Uploaded and created files are stored outside of the project file.

Comment: Is the file stored in C:/user/ocr/*.xlsm ?

Comment: yes  C:/user/ocr/pdfname.xlsm

Comment: Try to access it directly first in the browser. If that works, please check the python path it's returning. If both are correct then you have added a few-mode code to get the idea of what's happening in the function.

Answer (score 0):

please get more error info from django server. and list more code from `my views`.

Do you want to change file filename?